# C# Switch between program, and a java program

Tags: c#

I need some help figuring out how to switch between programs, the first application I can simply get from the taskmgr process. But the second program launches an Java applet and will be described as multiple java.exe's

Maybe there lays a solution around getting process name by the WindowTitle but since I am not that advanced in C# I am seeking for some help.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Prog1)
    {
        var prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Progam1");
        if (prc.Any())
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(prc[0].MainWindowHandle);
            ShowWindow(prc[0].MainWindowHandle, ShowWindowEmum.Program);
            Prog1 = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("A Java Applet");
        if (prc.Any())
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(prc[0].MainWindowHandle);
            ShowWindow(prc[0].MainWindowHandle, ShowWindowEmum.Java);
            Prog1 = true;
        }
    }
```

To clarify why this is needed both application run in a fullscreen borderless setting, and do not have a mouse or keyboard, just touchpanel which is limited to certain commands. Creating a touchable button to switch between both programs seems like a good solution.

Comment: Out of interest do you have control over the two programs? Just wondering if you could get them to do something like writing their process ID to a known location when they run or something else to make them a little easier to locate? Not to say that this approach won't work, just thinking about how else you might manage it...

Comment: @Chris I have access and control over both programs, though it's environment is restricted to certain area's due to the GPO. It should be able to save the process ID to a location. What are you suggesting here?

Comment: My understanding is that your problem is there are multiple processes identifying as java.exe and you need to find the right one. If that program records its process id (eg by writing it to `c:\myprogram\procid.txt` then your program can check that file for the process ID and thus identify the right process. I should stress that I have no idea if this approach would work and if so whether it is the best way. I've seen a few unix programs that reecord their procid in this way which is what made me think of it.